# BERT weight calculation

Tags: nlp, named-entity-recognition, bert-language-model

I am trying to understand the BERT weight calculation. Please suggest me some article which can help me to understand the internal workings of BERT. I have read articles from Medium.

- https://towardsdatascience.com/deconstructing-bert-distilling-6-patterns-from-100-million-parameters-b49113672f77
- https://towardsdatascience.com/deconstructing-bert-part-2-visualizing-the-inner-workings-of-attention-60a16d86b5c1

I am doing a small project to understand the Bert pretraining and fine-tuning from different sources. My idea is to calculate the weights of each token in their own sources and find avg of all weights to get a global model. Then this global model can be used to fine-tune in different sources.

- How can I find these weights, and how can average these weights from multiple sources?
- can I visualise it? Then how?

Also, note that I am trying to use Tensorflow version of the Bert implementation and planning to fine-tune for the NER task.

Comment: I think this is possible with Tensorflow-federated, Someone who knows please help me